# JQ to merge new values between 2 json files

Tags: json, jq

I'm a rookie wirh JQ.

I would like to merge 2 json files with JQ. But only for the present keys in first file.

---

First file (first.json)

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "foo": "bar1"
}
```

Second file (second.json)

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "foo": "bar2",
  "oof": "rab"
}
```

---

I already tried.

edit: <strike>jq -n '.[0] * .[1]' first.json second.json</strike>

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' first.json second.json
```

But the returned result is wrong.

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "foo": "bar2",
  "oof": "rab"
}
```

"oof" entry should not be present.

---

Expected merged.

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "foo": "bar2"
}
```

---

Best regards.

Comment: if you're up to consider an _alternative_ (i.e. non-jq) solution, then the same could be easily achieved with a _walk-path_ unix utility _jtc_: **`<first.json jtc -w'[:]<l>k' -u second.json -u'<l>t'`**. If you like, I can elaborate on the utility usage in a separate answer. I'm a developer of the `jtc` unix utility for JOSN processing.

Comment: With which version of `jq` does `jq -n '.[0] * .[1]' first.json second.json` not exit with `jq: error (at <unknown>): null (null) and null (null) cannot be multiplied`? (Which is to say, with `jq -n`, there's no automatic consumption of inputs, much less into a list, so it's unclear how you'd have a non-nil `.` at all; that's been my longstanding understanding, confirmed here with jq 1.6).

Comment: Edited command: **jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' first.json second.json**

Comment: jq version: **jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
jq -n '.
  | input as $first         # read first input
  | input as $second        # read second input
  | $first * $second        # make the merger of the two the context item
  | [ to_entries[]          # ...then break it out into key/value pairs
    | select($first[.key])  # ...and filter those for whether they exist in the first input
  ] | from_entries          # ...before reassembling into a single object.
' first.json second.json
```

...which properly emits:

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "foo": "bar2"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And here's a one-liner, which happens to be quite efficient:

```
jq --argfile first first.json '. as $in | $first | with_entries(.value = $in[.key] )' second.json
```